# Scala.js union types

Tags: scala, highcharts, scala.js

I'm using the HighCharts facade for Scala.js (v0.6.13) and am having difficulty configuring the cross hairs on my chart. Is it my understanding that when I see a Scala.js union type declaration of:

```
val crosshair: UndefOr[|[Boolean, CleanJsObject[YAxisCrosshair]]]
```

that the crosshair can be either a Boolean or a YAxisCrosshair?

If so my declaration with crosshair set to true compiles correctly:

```
override val yAxis: Cfg[YAxis] = YAxis(
  gridLineWidth = 0,
  minorGridLineWidth = 0,
  opposite = false,
  labels = YAxisLabels(
    align = "right",
    format = "{value:.8f}"
  ),
  crosshair = true
)
```

But when I set the crosshair to a YAxisCrosshair my project does not compile.

```
override val yAxis: Cfg[YAxis] = YAxis(
  gridLineWidth = 0,
  minorGridLineWidth = 0,
  opposite = false,
  labels = YAxisLabels(
    align = "right",
    format = "{value:.8f}"
  ),
  crosshair = YAxisCrosshair(
    snap = false,
    label = YAxisCrosshairLabel(
      format = "{value:.8f}"
    )
  )
)
```

The later results in a:

```
type mismatch;
  found   : com.highstock.config.YAxisCrosshair
  required: scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[scala.scalajs.js.|        [Boolean,com.highcharts.CleanJsObject[com.highstock.config.YAxisCrosshair]]]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer. This is what needed to be done:

```
override val yAxis: Cfg[YAxis] = YAxis(
  gridLineWidth = 0,
  minorGridLineWidth = 0,
  opposite = false,
  labels = YAxisLabels(
    align = "right",
    format = "{value:.8f}"
  ),
  crosshair = YAxisCrosshair(
    snap = false,
    label = YAxisCrosshairLabel(
      format = "{value:.8f}"
    )
  ): CleanJsObject[YAxisCrosshair]
)
```

Comment: You probably want tot highlight that `: CleanJSObject[YAxisCrosshair]` somehow ;) But yes, that's what needed to be done.